# Вертикальное выравнивание текста в слайдере?

Tags: css, slider, текст, выравнивание

В слайдере есть картинка и текст, картинка слева текст справа, не могу понять как сделать так, что б текст равнялся по вертикали по центру
[Скрин слайдера](https://prnt.sc/u0hrjl)

а вот сам код

```
    <div class="container header p-4 ">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="flexslider ">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img src="images/imgslider.png" class="float-left" alt="NA" >
            <p>«Анонимные Наркоманы» — это некоммерческое сообщество мужчин и женщин, для которых наркотики стали серьезной проблемой. Мы выздоравливающие зависимые, которые регулярно собираются для того, чтобы помогать друг другу оставаться чистыми</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/imgslider.png" class="float-left" alt="NA" >
            <p>Есть только одно условие для членства в Сообществе «Анонимные Наркоманы»  — желание прекратить употребление</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="images/imgslider.png" class="float-left"  alt="NA" >
            <p>Мы сами себя содержим на наши добровольные пожертвования. АН не связано ни с какой сектой, вероисповеданием, политическим направлением, организацией или учреждением, не вступает в полемику по каким бы то ни было вопросам, не поддерживает и не выступает против чьих бы то ни было интересов.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--  end flexslider  -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.7.2
 * https://www.woocommerce.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 and later license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 *
 */
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * FONT-FACE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESETS
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * BASE STYLES
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
   display: block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * DEFAULT THEME
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 60px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .loading .flex-viewport {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
.slides li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.slides li p { padding: 3%;height: 100%; }

.slides li img { width: 30%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте flexbox, вот как это сделать:

```css
.slides li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.slides li p { padding: 3%; }

.slides li img { width: 30%; }
```

```html
<ul class="slides">

  <li>
  
    <img src="https://cs.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/04/08/10/1365440248_1198480625.jpg">
    <p>
      «Анонимные Наркоманы» — это некоммерческое сообщество мужчин и женщин, для которых наркотики стали серьезной проблемой. 
      Мы выздоравливающие зависимые, которые регулярно собираются для того, чтобы помогать друг другу оставаться чистыми
    </p>
    
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Тогда текст спргивает вниз https://prnt.sc/u0ivge

Comment: @mi4i вы не прикрепили код своих стилей... вставьте сниппет (как я вставил код - что его запустить можно), убедитесь что он запускается - тогда можно будет его проанализировать и дать ответ. Проблема в каких то ваших стилях.

Comment: Добавил css слайдера

Comment: ну и прикручен bootstrap 4